# jQuery Mask Plugin with % sign

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use this mask plugin to simply have a textbox that shows a % sign at the end of the inputted text. Can someone tell me why it won't accept the % sign?

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

```
<input type="text" data-app-mask="'00%'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dm8Mb/342/)

Use this plugin [masked-input-plugin/](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

[plugins jquery link](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/)

[github link](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)

```
$(function () {
    $(".percent").mask("9?9%");
    $(".percent").on("blur", function () {
        var value = (this.value.length == 1) ? this.value + '%' : this.value;
        $(this).val(value);
    })
});
```

Comment: I would like to stick with the original plugin if possible. Is it not possible with this current plugin?